# Return Values not existing in table or not equal to a value

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables (SQL) EntityAttachment EA and UnitInventory UI.  UI.StockNumber can have attachments (documents) that are stored in the EntityAttachment table.

I am trying to figure out which Distinct UI.StockNumber have no entries in the EA table at all (meaning no documents) and combine that list with Distinct UI.StockNumber that have entries but don't have EA.Extension = 'jpg'.  So really, I am looking for UI.StockNumber that do not have extension = 'jpg'.

UI.UnitInventoryID = EA.EntityID

It's easy to join the two tables and filter out the EA.Extensions = 'jpg', but then I miss the ones that don't exists at all in the EA table.  I am lost and have been trying for far too long.  I also was able to return all the NULL values (ones that don't exist at all in the EA table), but then I missing the ones that have extensions of pdf, xls, etc. but not jpg.

Is this enough info to help?  I am struggling on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ui.stocknumber
FROM unitinventory ui
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM entityattachment
    WHERE entityid = ui.unitinventoryid 
        AND extension = 'jpg'
    );
```

Or:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ui.stocknumber
FROM unitinventory ui
LEFT JOIN entityattachment ea
ON ea.entityid = ui.unitinventoryid 
WHERE ea.extension IS NULL
    OR ea.extension <> 'jpg';
```

Comment: Option 2 would have been my approach.

Comment: They work, but now I need to join another table to filter out units that are active and certain types of units.  Where do I add this layer in?  The table is UnitMaster UM on um.[Stock Number] = ui.[StockNumber].

Comment: @JordonGriffith If you need other request, IMO you may need to post other question. Remember to add table structure, sample data and expected output with explanation on how to achieve that result. (In your comment I think may be you just simply need to add an INNER JOIN, or may be more complex than that?). Anyway, If my query work for your first question, may you mark that as answer for others to refer to.